# According to MO theory, why is the dilithium cation more stable than the dilithium anion?

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, stability

According to molecular orbital theory, $\ce{Li2}$ fills up two electrons in the $\sigma_\mathrm{g2s}$ molecular orbital; 
$\ce{Li2+}$ fills up one electron in the $\sigma_\mathrm{g2s}$ MO, and 
$\ce{Li2-}$ fills up two electrons in the $\sigma_\mathrm{g2s}$ MO and one electron in $\sigma^*_\mathrm{u2s}$, resulting in the same bond order for the ions.

I first thought that $\ce{Li2+}$ is stable, because they don't have paired electrons in $\sigma_\mathrm{g2s}$, therefore there is no pairing energy.
I soon found that $\ce{Li2+}$ is stable, but someone said it is due to the unfilled antibonding orbital. Is this a right explanation?

Because $\ce{Li2}$ is homonuclear, the weight that imposed on each $\mathrm{2s}$ $\ce{Li}$ atomic orbital would be almost the same. Even though $\ce{Li2-}$ is unstable by filling an antibonding orbital, it will be offset by filling two electrons into the bonding orbital and it has the same bond order as $\ce{Li2+}$ does.

What am I missing now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all some visual aid: an MO Diagram for $\ce{Li2}$.

[image: MO Diagram for dilithium]

The concept of bond order allows a very rough estimate of stability. Here we get $\mathrm{BO}(\ce{Li2})=1$, $\mathrm{BO}(\ce{Li2+})=0.5$, and $\mathrm{BO}(\ce{Li2-})=0.5$. So in first approximation, $\ce{Li2-}$ and $\ce{Li2+}$ are equally stable, while $\ce{Li2}$ more stable. But we can consider some more details:

> I first thought that $\ce{Li2+}$ is stable, because they don't have paired electrons in $\sigma_{g2s}$, therefore there is no pairing energy.

Adding a second electron to some orbital, would at first double the energy of that bond. But it also introduces some electron-electron repulsion between the two. This however is usually smaller than the gained bonding energy. So the contribution of the $\sigma_\mathrm{g2s}$ contribution in $\ce{Li2}$ is a little less than double its contribution in $\ce{Li2+}$. Please take this last statement with care, because things are more complex than that.

> I soon found that $\ce{Li2+}$ is stable, but someone said it is due to the unfilled antibonding orbital. Is this a right explanation?

Basically yes. The thing is, that the energy split of bonding and anti-bonding orbitals is not symmetric with respect to the originating atomic orbitals. The anti-bonding orbital is a little bit higher, than what the bonding orbital is lowered:

$$
E(\sigma^*_\mathrm{u2s}) - E(\mathrm{2s}) > 
E(\mathrm{2s}) - E(\sigma^*_\mathrm{g2s})
$$

This is because if you add more electrons, you add more electron-electron repulsion. In case of $\ce{Li2-}$ this means the electron in the anti-bonding orbital is more destabilizing (with respect to $\ce{Li2}$), than what the additional electron in the bonding orbital is stabilizing (when going from $\ce{Li2+}$ to $\ce{Li2}$).

> Because $\ce{Li2}$ is homonuclear, the weight that imposed on each $\mathrm{2s}$ $\ce{Li}$ atomic orbital would be almost the same.

Not just almost. The electronic wave function **must** follow the symmetry of the molecular structure, therefore the weights of the orbitals have to be **exactly** the same. But this argument is not really helpful for this question.